# oAuth2 between SPA React front and NodeJs express bac

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am building an API in NodeJS with express and a SPA front with React. I want to keep the domains distincts i.e. *api.domain.com* and *ui.app.com*.

How should the authentication be done on the API side?
So far, I implemented the code flow with **PKCE** on the client side, so I get a valid access token, along with a JWT *id_token*. The library I am using is also capable of refreshing the token.

When passing the JWT *id_token* to the API (via header) I can also validate and verify the JWT token using the well known public key certificate, hence being certain that the request comes from the logged in user, and granting access.

Is this the proper way to secure the API?

In case I need to do proper authorisation (using RBAC or gRPC), is the JWT id_token enough or should I rather pass the access token (which isn’t JWT) and use that token to request identity data and roles/permissions?

Answer (score 0):

What you've described seems to fit the web app client type:

> web application
> A web application is a confidential client running on a web
> server.  Resource owners access the client via an HTML user
> interface rendered in a user-agent on the device used by the
> resource owner.  The client credentials as well as any access
> token issued to the client are stored on the web server and are
> not exposed to or accessible by the resource owner.

[RFC6749-Sec2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749.html#section-2.1)

Which would help alleviate some of your current problems.

Your backend/API would be serving the "client" role as the OAuth 2.0 framework describes it (as opposed to what we think of when we say "client-side", namely, the frontend running in a browser).

So, you can do the authorization code flow (PKCE isn't necessarily needed, but it only helps to have). Then, your backend will receive the tokens from the authorization server.

Your last paragraph is a little confusing.
Are you sure the access token is *not* a JWT? While they don't necessarily have to be, it's almost ubiquitously adopted with OAuth 2.0.
If you use the web app setup, the backend will have the id token returned directly to it, and it can use that to make additional decisions or use the userinfo endpoint. The id token is intended for the OAuth 2.0 client or the Relying Party as OIDC calls it.

> OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0
> [RFC6749] (Hardt, D., “The OAuth 2.0 an Authorization Framework,” October 2012.)
> protocol. It enables Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based
> on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to
> obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an interoperable and
> REST-like manner.

[OIDC-Sec1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Introduction)

Using the web app type for your setup also helps protect the tokens from being stolen or abused since they're returned directly to the backend rather than the frontend where they'd be easier to access.

Comment: The oAuth2 vendor I'm using (Ory) returns an access token which is NOT JWT. Only the id token is. There might be some property somewhere to configure this behaviour, I'll dig around some more.

Comment: I am still a bit confused wether my scenario is "web application" or "user-agent-based". The backend does not render the interface (the HTML). The client code (React app) is public, downloaded from a separate DNS entry.

Comment: In case the backend is responsible of authenticating, then how is the flow between the front and back managed? call to the back are made via Ajax, meaning that there is no redirection to the back. What happens when a call is made to the back which returns 401: should the back rather return a 302 to the user agent, which redirects the user to the Authorization server? then the AS returns the token to the back? how does the front then keeps track of authorization?

Comment: https://www.ory.sh/docs/oauth2-oidc/jwt-access-token#jwt-access-tokens

I agree it's a little bit fuzzy. However, it doesn't say the backend renders the user interface, it says "...access the client via an HTML user interface rendered in a user-agent..."

To initiate authorization you just need to send the user to the authorize endpoint of the authorization server and include any necessary parameters. You can do it with a redirect.

Comment: After the user authenticates with the authz server, the user is redirected back to the app. It'll contain the authorization code and ideally goes directly to the server to extract, but then you have to redirect to another page with a UI for the user.

Comment: With the authz code, your backend makes a call to the token endpoint of the authz server. If successful, meaning the authz server authenticates your backend (the oauth client) and the authz code is valid, tokens are sent as a response directly to your backend.

Comment: I'm not following your last comment, but hopefully, my other comments have cleared up some things.

Comment: indeed, access tokens can be easily switched to JWT. As for the auth flow, my question is rather "which party is responsible of initiating the redirect to the auth server and fetch/receive the access token". If it is the backend, that means that when the front calls the back with Ajax, the back needs to tell the front to redirect to the auth server, which will use the backend callback uri to pass the token, and then the back redirects to the front uri. I'll try to clarify the scenario in the question. Currently the front handles the flow, keeps the token in storage and passes it to the back.

Comment: The backend redirects the front to the authz server. User authenticates and authorizes. Then, the user gets redirected to the backend callback url with an authz code, not a token. The backend then makes a call directly to the authz server with the code to get the token sent back directly to it. In both cases the backend is initiating. In the second step to get the token, the frontend is not involved. You can get the token, create some session id that maps to it, then send that id to the frontend to store in a cookie.